# Substitution lemma explanation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From the book "Verification of Sequential and Concurrent Programs".

"For all the expressions s and t, all assertions p, all simple or subscripted variables u of the same type as t and all proper states σ

i) σ(s[u:=t]) = σ [ u:=σ(t) ] (s)

ii)σ ⊨ p[u:=t] iff σ[u:=σ(t)] ⊨ p"

How can I use this to show that p[x:=1][y:=2] is equivalent to p[y:=2][x:=1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we have to understand what does the **Substitution Lemma** [page 47] mean.

We have *expressions* $s$ and $t$ [see page 31], a variable $u$ and a *substitution* $s[u := t]$ whose result [see page 43] is the expression obtained from $s$ with the replacement of $u$ by $t$.

Thus, *(i)* of the above Lemma roughly says that the "object" that state $\sigma$ assigns to the expression resulting from the replacement of variable $u$ with term $t$ into term $s$ is the same as that assigned by state $\sigma'$ to $s$, where the new state $\sigma'=\sigma[u:\sigma(t)]$ differs from $\sigma$ only in that it assigns to $u$ the "object" $\sigma(t)$ [see page 36].

The same for *(ii)*: in this case we have that two *assertions*: $p$ and $p[u:=t]$, and two "corresponding" states that satisfy them [see page 41].

Finally [see page 42], we have that two *assertions* $p$ and $q$ are *equivalent* when, for all proper states $\sigma$, we have that:

> $\sigma \vDash p \text { iff } \sigma \vDash q$.

Thus, in order to prove that:

> $p[x := 1][y := 2]$ is equivalent to $p[y := 2][x := 1]$,

we have to use part *(ii)*.

Consider a state $\sigma$; we have that $\sigma \vDash p[x:=1][y:=2]$ iff $\sigma [x:=σ(1)][y:= σ(2)] \vDash p$, by the **Lemma**.

[*Note* that [page 33] "the integer constant $1$ denotes the integer number $1$"; thus, the value of $\sigma(1)$ will be the number $1$, and so on.]

But $x$ and $y$ are simple variables, and thus the state $\sigma'= \sigma [x:=σ(1)][y:= σ(2)]$ is the same as $\sigma''= \sigma [y:= σ(2)][x:=σ(1)]$.

Thus, we apply again the **Lemma** to get:

> $\sigma [y:= σ(2)][x:=σ(1)] \vDash p$ iff $\sigma \vDash p[y:=2][x:=1]$.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a more clear and detailed explanation. Thanks a ton!